# IsPostBack Issue

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-update, 3-tier

I am trying to do a 3 tier volunteers sign up for packaging session system. First, on the page load, I get the details of certain packaging session:

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string packingID = Request.QueryString["id"];

            packingIndv = packing.getPacking(packingID);
            if (packingIndv == null)
            {
                lbl_msg.Text = "Error in getting packing session details!";
            }
            else
            {
                lbl_ID.Text = packingIndv.packingID;
                lbl_date.Text = packingIndv.date.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); ;
                lbl_location.Text = packingIndv.location;
                lbl_volunteerAvailable.Text = packingIndv.volunteerAvailable.ToString();
                lbl_status.Text = packingIndv.status;
            }
        }
```

After that, volunteers can click on the join button, and the program will execute:

In presentation layer after join button is on click:

```
string userLogged = Session["userLogged"].ToString();
        UserBLL user = new UserBLL();
        string userID = user.getUserIDByName(userLogged);

        PackingBLL packing = new PackingBLL();
        string msg = "";
        msg = packing.joinPacking(userID, lbl_ID.Text);
        lbl_msg.Text = msg;
```

In business logic layer:

```
public string joinPacking(string userID, string packingID)
    {
        string returnMessage = "";

        if(returnMessage.Length == 0)
        {
            Packing packing = new Packing(userID, packingID);
            Boolean success = packing.checkJoinedSession();
            if (success)
            {
                returnMessage += "Same volunteer cannot join same packing session for more than once! <br/>";
            }
            else
            {
                int nofRows = 0;
                nofRows = packing.joinPacking();

                if (nofRows > 0)
                {
                    returnMessage = "Request to volunteer for packing session saved successfully.";
                    int successUpdate = packing.updateRemaining();
                    if (successUpdate > 0)
                    {
                        getPacking(packingID);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    returnMessage = "Error! Please try again.";
                }
            }
        }

        return returnMessage;
    }
```

In data access layer:

```
 public int updateRemaining()
    {
        int result = 0;

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(FFTHDb.connectionString)) // get your connection string from the other class here
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE PackingSession SET volunteerAvailable = volunteerAvailable + 1 WHERE packingID = '" + packingID + "'", connection);
            connection.Open();
            result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

For every join from each volunteer, the volunteer available will be increased by one. What I am trying to do is from the page load, I display the details of packaging session. Then when volunteer joins it, the volunteerAvailable will straight away increased by one. All my database works perfectly, it just wont increase the volunteer available automatically after each successful update sql statement, as in I have to refresh the browser in order to see the changes.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sounds like you are updating the value *too early* in the lifecycle, before the DAL returns the updated value. Attach a debugger and inspect the value when assigned to the applicable control. I would recommend Data Binding.

Comment: Would you mind to show me some examples?

Comment: @Gwen Just make sure to use `lbl_volunteerAvailable.Text = packingIndv.volunteerAvailable.ToString()` *after* the update (and make it read from the database) in the PostBack. For databinding, see [Data Binding in ASP.NET Web Forms](http://sqlmag.com/aspnet/data-binding-aspnet-web-forms) or other resources. I recommend databinding in PreRender.

Comment: I thought I did that in my business logic layer already?

Comment: @Gwen You need to tell the View/Control to update with the *new* value. As it is now, `lbl_volunteerAvailable.Text` is only set when it is *not* a PostBack. The value should update after pressing F5 (i.e. new page load). Databinding can hide the details, e.g. it would look like `<asp:Label ID='available Text='<% AvailableCount %>' />`, where, in the code-behind `protected string AvailableCount { get { return AvailableCountFromDal() } }`.

Comment: @Gwen You need to tell the View/Control (`lbl_volunteerAvailable.Text`) to update with the *new* value *after* it has been changed in the DAL. E.g. *after* performing `packing.updateRemaining()`. The `Load` event fires first, *before* the `Click` event. So any code in the `Load` event does *not* have access to the new numbers. Assign the updated value to `lbl_volunteerAvailable.Text` in the `Click` event or in the `PreRender` event.